# mongoDb find number of entries in a document and distinct entries by field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoid, mongodb-query

My document structure is:

```
[{
    "l": {
    "ln": "Hyderabad",

    },
    "cid": "customer1",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Hyderabad",

    },
    "cid": "customer2",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Delhi",

    },
    "cid": "customer3",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Delhi",

    },
    "cid": "customer3",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Bangalore",

    },
    "cid": "customer1",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Bangalore",

    },
    "cid": "customer5",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Bangalore",

    },
    "cid": "customer6",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}, {
    "l": {
    "ln": "Bangalore",

    },
    "cid": "customer6",
    "created": ISODate("2015-07-20T13:15:45.198        Z")
}]
```

My o/p should be:

```
[{
    "ln": "Hyderabad",
    "entries": 2,
    "numberofdistinctcustomers": 2,
    "customers": [
    "customer1",
    "customer2"
    ]
} {
    "ln": "Delhi",
    "entries": 2,
    "numberofdistinctcustomers": 1,
    "customers": [
    "customer3"
    ]
} {
    "ln": "Bangalore",
    "entries": 4,
    "numberofdistinctcustomers": 3,
    "customers": [
    "customer1",
    "customer5",
    "customer6"
    ]
}]
```

Could anyone help me on this ? I understand for this we need to use `$group` by ln to find the `entries`. How to find number of distinct `cids`?

please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to get expected output.

First you need to group by `l.ln` and then get distinct `customers` using `$addToSet`. To get `numberofdistinctcustomers` you can use `$size` operator in projection.

The query will be like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
    _id: "$l.ln",
    "entries": {
        $sum: 1
    },
    "dis": {
        $addToSet: "$cid"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "ln": "$_id",
    "entries": 1,
    "customers": "$dis",
    "numberofdistinctcustomers": {
        "$size": "$dis"
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: @user1920 What error you are getting? You might be missing something while implementing above query.

Comment: I am getting the below error : Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0 ()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37 ([object Object],[object Object])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866 @(shell):17 uncaught exception: aggregate failed: { "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$size'", "code" : 15999, "ok" : 0 } If I remove "numberofdistinctcustomers": { "$size": "$dis" } it is working fine
@Vishwas